# Немогу прошить stm32

Tags: stm32, микроконтроллеры, прошивка

Мне нужно делать проект с применением stm32. До этого я работал с arduino, и подобных проблем не было. Я компилирую такой, автоматически сгенерированный посредством cubeMX,  код:

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
     HAL_Delay(500); 
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Используя такой make скрипт:

```
##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.5.2] date: [Mon Feb 03 16:34:48 MSK 2020]
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = test


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Src/main.c \
Src/stm32f1xx_it.c \
Src/stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_gpio_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_exti.c \
Src/system_stm32f1xx.c

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32f103xb.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else

CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif

HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S

#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m3

# fpu
# NONE for Cortex-M0/M0+/M3

# float-abi


# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS =

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32F103xB


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES =

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IInc \
-IDrivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32F103C8Tx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys
LIBDIR =
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))


$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 

    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@



$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)

    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@



$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile

    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

    $(SZ) $@



$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)

    $(HEX) $< $@



$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)

    $(BIN) $< $@    



$(BUILD_DIR):

    md $@


#######################################

# clean up

#######################################

clean:

    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)



#######################################

# dependencies

#######################################

-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)



# *** EOF ***
```

Однако, получив файл, при попытке прошить stm32 через st-link и stm32_st-link_utitity, я получаю ошибку: `This file is empty or corrupted!`

**UPD**
[Выходной файл](https://yadi.sk/d/X7IrjmEfcvN_qg)
**UPD2**
Изменил исходник.

Comment: Какой файл на выходе вы получаете. Какое его расширение.

Comment: При компиляции, я могу выставить любое расширение, я ставлю `.elf`.

Comment: Для stm32 stlink utility нужен hex или bin. Сконвертируйте и добавьте к вопросу. Хочу посмотреть, что не так с выходным файлом

Comment: Добавил выходной файл.

Comment: А вас не смущает, что файл с расширением hex, а содержимое у него elf. Elf файл содержит много лишней информации, связывающую прошивку с исходным кодом для того чтобы пошагово отлаживать код в дальнейшем. St-link не умеет работать  с такими файлами. В результате что то у вас не то в конвертации elf файла в hex, попробуйте ручками это сделать без makefile с помощью утилиты objcopy

Comment: @Roman Ozhegov, попробовал. Выдаёт новою ошибку: `File corrupted. Two or more segments defines the same memory zone.`

Comment: У меня тоже elf не очень конвертится. Hex вообще не конвертится, а бинарник выходит на 68 байт, что очень мало. Так что проблема в компилляции. Выложите новые Ваши файлы, может с ними будет понятнее.

Comment: Еще заметил. У Вас в дефайнах STM32F103xB, а скрипт линкера для STM32F103C8Tx. Да, они отличаются лишь объемом памяти, но все-таки...